# How could include header files when installing program by using ./configure command

Tags: linux, installation, include-path, tmux, libevent

I'm trying to install tmux program in CentOS from source. 
Since the machine is a server, I should install it on my own home directory.

I downloaded the source code and tried to configure. 
But that doesn't work because the tmux program needs libevent library. I should install libevent in advance.

I installed libevent in local folder. this library(?) or program(?) folder has three folder. bin, lib, include. I changed environment variable such as PATH to indicate bin folder and LD_LIBRARY_PATH to indicate lib folder.

Now I guess I could install tmux. I command

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/tmux
```

but same error occured...

```
configure: error: "libevent not found"
```

What's wrong in my progress?
I guess the problem is that I didn't include(?) include folder of libevent. so configure command couldn't find that folder and header files in it. But I don't know how to let them know where the folder exist!

I searched but failed... could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The configure script creates a file named "config.log" which contains the output of the different tests that it executed during its run.

The contents of the file should tell you what is wrong and what test is failing.

Why are you not installing a package provided by the distro you are using?

Comment: I cannot install a package since I don't have permission. It's a server and not mine. I'm parasitic on this machine.. TT

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `configure` where to find your local installation of `libevent`. I use the following:

```
DIR=~/local
./configure LIBEVENT_CFLAGS="-I$DIR/include" \
            LIBEVENT_LIBS="-L$DIR/lib" \
            CFLAGS="-I$DIR/include" \
            LDFLAGS="-L$DIR/lib" --prefix=$DIR
```

where I install both `tmux` and `libevent` under `~/local/`.